# Why does netlogo think that this input is 0?

Tags: netlogo

I have the code:

```
  to calculate-road-length
  if [pcolor] of patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor  = 7[ 
  set this-thing road-number
  set plabel road-number 
  set number lput road-number number]
```

Where road-number is an input. Why do I get the error "LPUT expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead" even when I enter a number? Any help would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `road-number`, it is with `number`: [`lput`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#lput) expects the second parameter to be a list. Have you initialized `number` to a list?

You probably want to put `set number []` in your `setup` procedure.

(`number` is a strange name for a list, by the way. Should it be plural, i.e., `numbers`?)

Comment: How should I initialize number ?

Comment: `set number []` in your setup procedure will initialize it to the empty list.